SQL to use an array of tables to dynamically join
My company currently uploads a contacts list to Google BigQuery once a month, which generates a brand new table with a new name. All the tables follow the same format: OUT#####, where the #'s are the unix timestamp of when it was created. I can easily get a list of tables using select table_id from gbqstuff.__TABLES__, and it gives me the list.
Is there a way to take that list of table IDs as an array generate a new Select statement to UNION them all into one table for use in PowerBI or other reporting tools? Right now they go into a view and modify the view once a month to add the next table name to it...
I've done a lot of digging and they didn't even have a good way to get the table names. I can do this now via the method above, and I know I could use VB6 or similar to build the SQL string. But can I do it all in SQL?

They've built and maintain a view for this. While I'm not a fan of the design (should be ONE table, with an extra column as the first part of the primary key, and potentially table partitions... but maybe BigQuery isn't so good at that), I suggest you query the view. It's what it's there for.

If the tables has the same prefix and structure, BigQuery supports query multiple tables using a wildcard table:
SELECT 
*
FROM
  `project.dataset.OUT*`
WHERE
 _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '1712325706' -- pseudocolumn that allows filter tables


Each row in the wildcard table contains a special column, _TABLE_SUFFIX, which contains the value matched by the wildcard character.


After a lot of back and forth with a few dbas this is what we came up with.
Posted to pastebin also Incase someone else needs it down the road. https://pastebin.com/UcW1qghn
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(
      SELECT string_agg(  
          CONCAT("select id, firstName, otherColumns from project.database." , table_id, " ")
          , "UNION ALL \n"
       )
    FROM `project.database.__TABLES__`
    WHERE table_id like 'LeadingTableName%' and table_id not like '%soupSucks'
    )

